# How to write a condition if the number is equal, greater than two digits, or less than two digits

Tags: php

How to write a condition if the number is equal, greater than two digits, or less than two digits
Example:

```
$n1 = 10;
$n2 = 12;

if($n1 and $n2 /*If is equal to, plus or minus two digits  */ )
  { return true; }
```

Example:
$n1 == $n2 + 2 digits or -2 digits = true

How is this implemented in a conditional ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? There are already two numbers in your example, so to which of these should that condition apply? "Greater than to digits" would mean `x >= 100` - so why not check for that?

Comment: what do you mean by **two digits** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am supposing you want to compare if n1 is in the range of $n2+2 or n2-2.

For that this code should work:

```
$n1 = 10;
$n2 = 12;

if($n1 <= $n2+2 || $n1 >= $n2-2){ 
  return true; 
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: your answer dosent provide any description